# Is possible resize grids and its content in kendo-ui?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is possible resize grids and its content in kendo-ui? I want to use it for a responsive web application.
I mean resizable columns, rows and the content inside (text, images, ..)

Answer (score 2):

The kendo grid columns can be resized as long as you set resizable to be true when making the grid initially.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                       //datasource stuff
                    },
                    height: 350,
                    sortable: true,
                    resizable: true, <--this is the one to be set to make resizing possible
                    pageable: true,
```

Comment: Rows and content inside (text, images, ..), can be resizable?

Comment: Here's the example that the answer code comes from: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/column-resizing.html It doesn't show the text resizing.

Comment: But is possible resize text. is not?